# How to read year month date format from using sqlite, c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

**My Problem:**

I've got data in tables which is of format YYYY-MM ex: 2001-02.
When I query from my db, and store those values in lists to be presented onto a listview, **the output becomes 1/1/2001 12:00 am (Don't want it in this date time format).**

```
   string sql6 = "select YYMM, TotalTrans  from t2 where cast(TotalTrans as int) < 1000";
   SQLiteCommand command3 = new SQLiteCommand(sql6, sqlite_conn);


   SQLiteDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader3.Read())
   {


       DateTime yyyymm;  

       if (DateTime.TryParse(reader3["YYMM"].ToString(), out yyyymm))
       {
           YYMM.Add(yyyymm);

       }
   }
```

Based on SO user help, I tried to run modify the query and use strftime.

**But now I don't get ANY values in my list** (YYMMt21 - which I use to populate the listview)

```
        string sql13 = "SELECT YYMM FROM t2 WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', YYMM) = '2002-02'";

        SQLiteCommand cmd4 = new SQLiteCommand(sql13, sqlite_conn);

        SQLiteDataReader rdr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr4.Read())
        {

           // int TotalTranst21;


          int yyyyyy;
            if (int.TryParse(rdr4["YYMM"].ToString(), out  yyyyyy) )
            {
                YYMMt21.Add(yyyyyy);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but it's either a date (with a day) and you format it for display as a string, or it's not a date in which  case why are you converting it to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what do you want to show in your list? `YYYY-MM`, just like database? If so, don't parse to `int` neither `DateTime`, just use returned string.

Now, the code...

SQL:

```
 string sql6 = "select YYMM, TotalTrans  from t2 where cast(TotalTrans as int) < 1000";
 //If you are just using YYMM, why choosing two columns???

 string sql13 = "SELECT YYMM FROM t2 WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', YYMM) = '2002-02'";
 //If dates in database are already in YYYY-MM format, why use STRFTIME?
 //STRFTIME will fail (return NULL), as YYYY-MM is not a valid SQLite date string
```

Parsing:

```
   //if (DateTime.TryParse(reader3["YYMM"].ToString(), out yyyymm))
   //if (int.TryParse(rdr4["YYMM"].ToString(), out  yyyyyy) )
   //No sense at all. Just use supplied string:
   YYMMt21.Add(rdr4["YYMM"].ToString());
```

Conclusion:

```
SQLiteCommand command3 = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT YYMM FROM t2 WHERE TotalTrans<1000", sqlite_conn);
SQLiteDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
while (reader3.Read()) {
    YYMM.Add(reader3["YYMM"].ToString());
}
```

... is enough!

Answer (score 2):

You should have your program logic do the date formatting for you. In your code, your `DateTime` object is what is formatting your string the way you're seeing it --it doesn't matter how the date string looks in SQL, it will become a `DateTime` object [hence the `DateTime.TryParse()`].

Take a look at the MS documentation on date formatting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As a side note, unlike other SQL database systems, there is no field type of DateTime in SQLite. You can store them as integers or text, and utilize the built-in functions referenced in the link as follows.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use full format for store date: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
does not matter if you need to store only the time or only date

also you can use other format for date and time:

**REAL**

as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.

**INTEGER** 
as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Only after that,  strftime will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string Mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(rd4["YYMM"]).ToString("yyyy");
```

You will have as result  year

if you use this:

```
string Mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(rd4["YYMM"]).ToString("d");
```

You will have result dd-mm-yyyy (or as the regional setting)